# Send specific decoded JSON value from response to php

Tags: php, json, ajax

another question from me after several hours looking for answer/method from other user question.

So here quick detail:

1. 1.php sending input field value to 2.php using AJAX
2. 2.php getting the value via $_POST and use it to send request to other server API
3. I got JSON response, decoded and echoed them in 2.php
4. 1.php got result from 2.php's decoded JSON response inside a div
5. By using a button inside the div, i populate/fill some input field in 1.php with value i got from 2.php

And the problem is im getting stuck with getting specific decoded JSON value, say i want $decodedname or $decoded['response']['name']. Right now im getting all the response from 2.php

1.php

```
<div>
  <label class="col-form-label"><b>Card Number</b></label><br>                                       
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="card" name="card">
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" onclick="return 
  checkcard()">Check
</button>

<div id="msg">
</div>

<label class="col-form-label"><b>NICK</b></label><br>                                           

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="nick" name="nick">

<label class="col-form-label"><b>NAME</b></label><br>                                           

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return autoFill()">

<script type="text/javascript">     
    var global_data = '';

    function checkcard()
    {
        var name = $('#card').val();
        var dataString ='card='+ name;                                   
        $.ajax({                                     
            type:"POST",
            url:"../loader/2.php",                               
            data:dataString,                                     
            cache:false,
            success: function(data){
                global_data = data;
                var getname = data.name; ----- i've also tried to set var getname = data.encode
                $('#msg').html(data);
           }
        }) 
        return false;   
    }                   

    function autoFill() {                                                        
        $('#nick').val(global_data);
        $('#name').val(getname);
        return false;
    }    
</script>
```

2.php

```
$name = $decodedjson['response']['name'];
$encode = array('name' => $name);
echo json_encode($encode); <--- u want to get this specific value, not all the decoded json below this
---echoed other decoded response---
```

Comment: Please show us a dump of `$decodedjson`

Comment: Can you be more specific? What was the desired output? And what stopped you from getting that?

Comment: json string __must be echoed once__. If you do `echo $json1; echo $json2; echo $json3;` - result is __invalid json__.

Comment: @KoalaYeung, i want to fill some input field with specific json value, like field name with $decodedjson['response']['name'], and field city with $decodedjson['response']['city'], right now when i click the button to populate/fill the input field all i got is whole $decodedjson

Comment: Also open developers console and see result of request there.

Comment: @PatrickQ:
$decodedjson = json_decode($content, true);

resulting in php:

Comment: @PatrickQ:

result:
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [count] => 6
            [list] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [kdStatusPulang] => 0
                            [nmStatusPulang] => Sembuh
                        )

                )

        )

    [metaData] => Array
        (
            [message] => OK
            [code] => 200
        )

)

Comment: @ary431  I'm not seeing `name` in there anyway.  Also, please update your question with that information.  As you can see, it is quite hard to read things like that in comments as they don't support proper formatting.

Comment: @PatrickQ, ah yes, iam sorry here is the other response

Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [noKartu] => 0000206410151
            [name] => ARY SAPUTRA
            [hubunganKeluarga] => Anak
            [sex] => L
            [tglLahir] => null
            [tglMulaiAktif] => 28-09-2011
            [tglAkhirBerlaku] => 31-12-2050
            [city] => jakarta
 )

    [metaData] => Array
        (
            [message] => OK
            [code] => 200
        )

)